# Are there any TFS 2010 Dashboards that support multi-project queries?

Tags: tfs

Does anyone know of a TFS 2010 Dashboard that is able to utilize multi-project queries?  Our group has several distinct projects that must be managed at the same time.  TFS itself supports this.  Simply by excluding the Project = @Project (or whatever) we can get back the results we're looking for.  Our issue is that we would like to find a nice dashboard (like Telerik Work Item Manager) that also supports this.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the Telerik Work Item Manager does support this (just not by default or design).  The issue was that by default it filters on Area / Iteration.  By removing the filter we see everything that we need to.